# Finding a sum of next 3 elements in python list

Tags: python, list, sum

I need to write a python program that sums all next 3 elements of a list that has 1000 random numbers, and find the highest sum. I also need to find it in 30000 elements list and 1000000 elements list. All the numbers are positive.
example:
testlist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

expected output:
sum of:
(1, 2, 3)
(2, 3, 4)
(3, 4, 5) etc.

I tried this (I'm pretty new to python)

```
for i in [1,2,3]:
    with open(f"DANE/bloki{i}.txt", "r") as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
    lines_clear = []
    for line in lines:
        lines_clear.append(int(line.strip()))
# print(lines_clear)
max_sum_of_block = 0
for start in range(len(lines_clear)):
    for end in range(start, len(lines_clear)):
        sum_of_block = sum(lines_clear[start:end])
        max_sum_of_block = max(max_sum_of_block, sum_of_block)
print(max_sum_of_block)
```

Comment: For each index in the list, call `sum(items[index:index+3])`.  Keep track of whatever sum is the largest.  What is the difficulty?

Comment: By the way, this is a perfect illustration of "minimal reproducible example".   The first half of your code handles reading the list from a file, but that's not really what your question is about.  You could have replaced that code with a simple hardcoded list of integers.

Comment: @JohnGordon That advice would be appropriate if their reading part were correct.

Answer (score 1):

Combing `zip`, `sum`, and `max` makes this pretty simple:

```
>>> testlist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
>>> max(zip(*(testlist[i:] for i in range(3))), key=sum)
(8, 9, 10)
```

Breaking that down a little bit: first we slice the list three times with different offsets:

```
>>> [testlist[i:] for i in range(3)]
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

Then we `zip` those three together:

```
>>> list(zip(*(testlist[i:] for i in range(3))))
[(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 5), (4, 5, 6), (5, 6, 7), (6, 7, 8), (7, 8, 9), (8, 9, 10)]
```

If we take the `sum` of that we have:

```
>>> [sum(z) for z in zip(*(testlist[i:] for i in range(3)))]
[6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27]
```

So to get the triple with the highest sum, we take the `max` using the `sum` function as a key:

```
>>> max(zip(*(testlist[i:] for i in range(3))), key=sum)
(8, 9, 10)
```

Entirely separately from the question of how to find the maximum sum in the list of numbers is the question of how you load the list of numbers from a file, which isn't mentioned at all in the text of your question but looks problematic in the code:

```
for i in [1,2,3]:
    with open(f"DANE/bloki{i}.txt", "r") as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
    lines_clear = []
    for line in lines:
        lines_clear.append(int(line.strip()))
```

Note that the above code reads the files:

```
DANE/blok1.txt
DANE/blok2.txt
DANE/blok3.txt
```

in that order, and assigns the numbers in those files (one int per line) to `lines_clear`, in that order, *overwriting `lines_clear` each time*.

If you want to put the numbers from all three files into a single list, you probably want something more like:

```
nums = []
for i in range(1, 4):
    with open(f"DANE/bloki{i}.txt") as file:
        nums.extend(int(line.strip()) for line in file)
```

Comment: `(8, 9, 10)` is the tuple with the highest sum (27).